# Variable Not Passing Through Class

Tags: vba

I'm trying to write a simple program in Visual Basic that passes a variable through a class, calculates it, then returns it. My form "Pizza" has 2 groups with 3 Radio buttons each. When the Total button is clicked the pizza size price is added to the pizza crust price. I found through troubleshooting that its only adding "createPizza.Crust" + "createPizza.Size". What am I missing. Thank you for any help.

```
Form "Pizza"
Public Class Pizza

Private Sub btnTotal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTotal.Click
    If rThin.Checked = True Then
        createPizza.Crust = 1
    ElseIf rPan.Checked = True Then
        createPizza.Crust = 2
    ElseIf rStuff.Checked = True Then
        createPizza.Crust = 3
    End If

    If rSm.Checked = True Then
        createPizza.Size = 1
    ElseIf rMm.Checked = True Then
        createPizza.Size = 2
    ElseIf rLg.Checked = True Then
        createPizza.Size = 3
    End If

    lblTotal.Text = "Total: " + createPizza.PizTotal.ToString()

  End Sub
End Class
```

Class "createPizza"

```
Public Class createPizza

Public Shared Size As Double
Public Shared Crust As Double

Public Shared Property pizzaCrust As Double
    Get
        Return Crust
    End Get
    Set(ByVal crustpr As Double)
        If Crust = 1 Then
            crustpr = 1
        ElseIf Crust = 2 Then
            crustpr = 1.5
        ElseIf Crust = 3 Then
            crustpr = 3
        End If
        Crust = crustpr
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared Property pizzaSize As Double
    Get
        Return Size
    End Get
    Set(ByVal sizepr As Double)
        If Size = 1 Then
            sizepr = 10.0
        ElseIf Size = 2 Then
            sizepr = 12.5
        ElseIf Size = 3 Then
            sizepr = 15
        End If
        Size = sizepr
    End Set
End Property

Public Shared Function PizTotal() As Decimal
    Return pizzaCrust + pizzaSize
End Function

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PizTotal` function is only returning `Size + Crust` because your `pizzaSize` and `pizzaCrust` properties return the value of `Size` and `Crust` respectively.  I can see the code your have to calculate the costs in your property settings but you never call the setters for `pizzaSize` and `pizzaCrust` so the cost is never calculated.

Your `pizzaSize` and `pizzaCrust` properties don't make a whole lot of sense.  For example the crust property setting takes as input the price, but if the `Crust` is 1, 2, or 3 it resets the price, and then it stores the price in the `Crust` variable.  If you wrote the following logic:

```
Dim p as New createPizza
p.Crust = 2
p.pizzaCrust = 12345678
Dim price1 As Double = p.pizzaCrust
p.pizzaCrust = 12345678
Dim price2 As Double = p.pizzaCrust
```

At the `price1` will be 1.5 and `price2` will be 12345678 because pizzaCrust both uses the value of `Crust` and modifies `Crust`.   You are using the `Crust` variable for both the crust type and crust price and not distinguishing between them.  You should store the crust type in one variable and the cust cost in a different variable (or better just write a function that returns the curst cost based on the crust type of 1,2, or 3).

Comment: IntelliSense converted it to
    `Dim p As New createPizza
        createPizza.Crust = 2
        createPizza.pizzaCrust = 12345678
        Dim price1 As Double = createPizza.pizzaCrust
        createPizza.pizzaCrust = 12345678
        Dim price2 As Double = createPizza.pizzaCrust`

Wont this bypass the "pizzaCrust" and "pizzaSize" completely?

Answer (score 0):

I have updated class to suit for VBA.

Class **createPizza**

```
Private Size As Double
Private Crust As Double


Public Function PizTotal() As Double
    PizTotal = pizzaCrust + pizzaSize
End Function


Public Property Get pizzaCrust() As Double
    pizzaCrust = Crust
End Property

Public Property Let pizzaCrust(ByVal vNewValue As Double)
    Select Case vNewValue
    Case 1
        crustpr = 1
    Case 2
        crustpr = 1.5
    Case 3
        crustpr = 3
    End Select

    Crust = crustpr
End Property

Public Property Get pizzaSize() As Double
    pizzaSize = Size
End Property

Public Property Let pizzaSize(ByVal vNewValue As Double)
    Select Case vNewValue
    Case 1
        sizepr = 10#
    Case 2
        sizepr = 12.5
    Case 3
        sizepr = 15
    End Select

    Size = sizepr
End Property
```

**Module** 
sample code

```
Sub sample()
    Dim a As New createPizza
    a.pizzaCrust = 2
    a.pizzaSize = 3

    MsgBox a.PizTotal
End Sub
```